# Make Datetime Series from separate year, month, and date columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

How can we use columns 'Yr', 'Mo' and 'Dy' to create a new column with type Datetime and set it as the index of the Pandas DataFrame?

[image: type]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should convert `Yr` to a four-digit int, i.e. 1961 or 2061.  This is unambiguous and, if you use the approach below, the format YYYY-MM-DD is required.  That's because Pandas uses `format='%Y%m%d'` in pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py:

```
# From pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py, if you pass a DataFrame or dict
values = to_datetime(values, format='%Y%m%d', errors=errors)
```

So, to take an example:

```
from itertools import product

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(444)

datecols = ['Yr', 'Mo', 'Dy']
mapper = dict(zip(datecols, ('year', 'month', 'day')))
df = pd.DataFrame(list(product([61, 62], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3])),
                  columns=datecols)
df['data'] = np.random.randn(len(df))
```

Here is `df`:

```
In [11]: df                                                                                                                                                   
Out[11]: 
    Yr  Mo  Dy      data
0   61   1   1  0.357440
1   61   1   2  0.377538
2   61   1   3  1.382338
3   61   2   1  1.175549
4   61   2   2 -0.939276
5   61   2   3 -1.143150
6   62   1   1 -0.542440
7   62   1   2 -0.548708
8   62   1   3  0.208520
9   62   2   1  0.212690
10  62   2   2  1.268021
11  62   2   3 -0.807303
```

Let's assume for the sake of simplicity that the true range is 1920 onward, i.e.:

```
In [16]: yr = df['Yr']                                                                                                                                        

In [17]: df['Yr'] = np.where(yr <= 20, 2000 + yr, 1900 + yr)                                                                                                  

In [18]: df                                                                                                                                                   
Out[18]: 
      Yr  Mo  Dy      data
0   1961   1   1  0.357440
1   1961   1   2  0.377538
2   1961   1   3  1.382338
3   1961   2   1  1.175549
4   1961   2   2 -0.939276
5   1961   2   3 -1.143150
6   1962   1   1 -0.542440
7   1962   1   2 -0.548708
8   1962   1   3  0.208520
9   1962   2   1  0.212690
10  1962   2   2  1.268021
11  1962   2   3 -0.807303
```

The second thing you need to do is rename the columns; Pandas is fairly strict about this if you pass in a mapping or DataFrame to `pd.to_datetime()`.  Here is that step and the result:

```
In [21]: df.index = pd.to_datetime(df[datecols].rename(columns=mapper))                                                                                       

In [22]: df                                                                                                                                                   
Out[22]: 
              Yr  Mo  Dy      data
1961-01-01  1961   1   1  0.357440
1961-01-02  1961   1   2  0.377538
1961-01-03  1961   1   3  1.382338
1961-02-01  1961   2   1  1.175549
1961-02-02  1961   2   2 -0.939276
1961-02-03  1961   2   3 -1.143150
1962-01-01  1962   1   1 -0.542440
1962-01-02  1962   1   2 -0.548708
1962-01-03  1962   1   3  0.208520
1962-02-01  1962   2   1  0.212690
1962-02-02  1962   2   2  1.268021
1962-02-03  1962   2   3 -0.807303
```

Lastly, here's one alternate through concatenating the columns as strings:

```
In [27]: as_str = df[datecols].astype(str)   
In [30]: pd.to_datetime( 
    ...:     as_str['Yr'] + '-' + as_str['Mo'] +'-' + as_str['Dy'], 
    ...:     format='%y-%m-%d' 
    ...:    )                                                                                                                                                 
Out[30]: 
0    2061-01-01
1    2061-01-02
2    2061-01-03
3    2061-02-01
4    2061-02-02
5    2061-02-03
6    2062-01-01
7    2062-01-02
8    2062-01-03
9    2062-02-01
10   2062-02-02
11   2062-02-03
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Notice again that this will assume the century for you.  If you want to be explicit, you need to follow the same approach as above for adding the correct century before defining `as_str`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Brad, this is how I fixed it

```
def adjustyear(x):
    if x >= 1800:
        x = 1900 + x
    else:
        x = 2000 + x
    return x

def parsefunc(x):
    yearmodified = adjustyear(x['Yr'])
    print(yearmodified)
    datetimestr = str(yearmodified)+str(x['Mo'])+str(x['Dy'])
    return pd.to_datetime(datetimestr, format='%Y%m%d', errors='ignore')

data['newindex'] = data.apply(parsefunc, axis=1)
data.index = data['newindex']
```